Losing the generic parameter when using Indexed Access syntax
Need help getting the method without losing the <T>, here is the code:
type Foo = {
    bar<T>(arg: T): T
}

type Bar = Foo['bar']

type Test = Bar<string> // Type 'Bar' is not generic.(2315)

Playground
Is there a way to get the method type without losing the generic argument?
I need to use the type of the method without losing it's 'genericness'. Also the <T> can not be lifted to the Foo itself (this is a simplified example, actually building something more complicated where the <T> is unknown at instantiation of the class but will be known on the respective method call)

The problem is that type Bar = <T>(arg: T) => T, not type Bar<T> = (arg: T) => T. Not sure how to solve that though

I found a workaround by creating a variable (means more memory usage): playground

That is a good idea HairyHandKerchief23
You can add 'declare' so there is no runtime overhead: Playground

• What is "value accessor syntax"?  Do you mean an indexed access type? • You're trying to instantiate a generic function's type argument the way you would instantiate a generic type's type argument. But generic functions and generic types aren't the same, nor does TS let you convert between them purely in the type system. You can use instantiation expressions if you have a value of the generic function type (the "creating a variable" workaround mentioned above). See linked q/a for more info

Changed "value accessor" to the "indexed access" in the title, my mistake
